# ASP.NET MVC 2: AJAX update and Html.Display()

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple form and within I'm using `Html.DisplayFor()` method to show some values. There is a submit button also within the form, which is triggering an update.

The question is how to "refresh" the Display method(using AJAX). The particular action method must return a `ActionResult`. I see the only solution in putting the display method in a partial view or is there any other option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery AJAX methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) fairly easily to do this. Wrap the area you want to update in a DIV and give it an ID (say "ajax_panel") and then call a jQuery function when your submit button is clicked:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/YourController/ActionMethod>',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#ajax_panel').html(data);
                }
            });
```

Get the ActionMethod() to return the View you want and use a partial view to render it. I found [this article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) useful when I tried to do something similar.